matplotlib cm.get_cmap(name, num_steps)
My python code uses
plt.cm.getcmap("coolwarm", num_steps)
This causes a deprecation warning.
The get_cmap function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.7 and will be removed in 3.11. Use matplotlib.colormaps[name] or matplotlib.colormaps.get_cmap() or pyplot.get_cmap() instead.
however - both suggested methods do not provide a "num_steps" parameter. How do I need to update my statement to be compatible?

In [6]: plt.cm.getcmap("coolwarm", num_steps)

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cm' has no attribute 'getcmap'

Could you please 'copy&paste' the code that raised a warning?

In [29]: import matplotlib
    ...: 
    ...: cw = matplotlib.colormaps['coolwarm']
    ...: cw10 = matplotlib.colormaps['coolwarm'].resampled(10)
    ...: print(cw.N, cw10.N)
256 10

In [30]: 

